# how to concat sql query using union operator

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String Query="select * from recommendation.sports WHERE feed LIKE'%"+s1+"%'

    UNION "select * from recommendation.software  WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION "select * from recommendation.website   WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION "select * from recommendation.others    WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION "select * from recommendation.business  WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'";
```

Comment: check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) out..

Comment: the above code work fine in mysql database,the same code use in jdbc i getting a compile time error Syntax error on token "UNION", [ expected

Comment: @R.J the above code work fine in mysql database,the same code use in jdbc i getting a compile time error Syntax error on token "UNION", [ expected i try to modify the code but it won't work,can u modify my code

Comment: using select * won't work if all tables don't have the exact column names, types and order.

Comment: you have an extra double-quote between each `UNION` and `select`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you mean this?

```
String Query = "select * from recommendation.sports WHERE feed LIKE '%" + s1 + "%' " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.software  WHERE feed LIKE '%" +s1+ "%' " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.website   WHERE feed LIKE '%" +s1+" %' " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.others    WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%' " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.business  WHERE feed LIKE '%" +s1+ "%'" ;
```

but I advise you to use `PreparedStatements` on the query to avoid `SQL Injection`.

```
String Query = "select * from recommendation.sports WHERE feed LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.software  WHERE feed LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.website   WHERE feed LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.others    WHERE feed LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')  " +
                "UNION " +
                "select * from recommendation.business  WHERE feed LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')" ;

PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(Query);
pstmt.setString(1, s1);
pstmt.setString(2, s1);
pstmt.setString(3, s1);
pstmt.setString(4, s1);
pstmt.setString(5, s1);
ResultSet _result = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

- [JAVA PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: @JVV your code work fine in mysql database but in jdbc,it getting an error can you re write the code using prepared statement..

Comment: @jvv String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Comment: @JVV String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 String Query="select * from recommendation.sports WHERE feed LIKE'%"+s1+"%'

    UNION select * from recommendation.software  WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION select * from recommendation.website   WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION select * from recommendation.others    WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'

    UNION select * from recommendation.business  WHERE feed LIKE '%"+s1+"%'";
```

Comment: ,sorry for said that your code also getting an error,your code work fine in mysql database but in jdbc,it getting an error

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor changes, please review it.

```
String Query="select * from recommendation.sports WHERE feed LIKE \'%"+s1+"%\'

    UNION select * from recommendation.software  WHERE feed LIKE \'%"+s1+"%\'

    UNION select * from recommendation.website   WHERE feed LIKE \'%"+s1+"%\'

    UNION select * from recommendation.others    WHERE feed LIKE \'%"+s1+"%\'

    UNION select * from recommendation.business  WHERE feed LIKE \'%"+s1+"%\'";
```

Try this and tell me if it works or not.